# JSP TableTag Sorting

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tags

I'm working on a legacy system that uses JSPs. Specifically, there is a `<display:table>` tag that allows the user to sort the columns of data. However, when the default tag is used, it sorts only alphabetically, by integer, or by double. I'm looking for a way to inject custom logic into the call stack so that I can use the `dataType` attribute of `<display:column>` to sort values like "$5,000,000.00" and not have "$5,100" listed before it.

I have a fully tested comparator that can be used by the sort mechanism.

I'm open to any ideas. These are the ones I have come up with:

- I've found some [other implementations](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html#column) that take a `comparator`. I plan to test this first to see if it will work with what I have currently. This type of change is a large systematic change with testing implications, however.
- Re-implement `TableTag` and `ColumnTag`. However, I can't find the actual source to see what these generally do. So much for the "Open Source" designation.

Answer (score 0):

use tld file to get the class corresponding class and you can inject your method in that class.

Comment: I'm no expert on JSP tags - do you know of any implementations that I could refer to to get an understanding of the tag generation?

Comment: Ok follow this link http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsptaglibraries.shtml not the best one but can help.